ncursesw6 compatiblity issues across distros
I didn't have much problem with ncursesw5 with my 32bit console app, but using ncursesw6 causes issues.  When I build the application on a Debian based OS, it requires version symbols for ncursesw6.
The Red Hat/Fedora based OSes don't provide a version that has version symbols.  You end up with no version information available (required by ./appname) (and a core dump).
The OpenSUSE based OSes are using ncursestw6 (threaded) version so you end up with something like /lib/libncursesw.so.6: version `NCURSESW6_5.3.20021019' not found (required by ./appname)
What is the solution so that you can compile an application using ncursesw6 and use it across different distros?
I recall trying static linking only ncurses itself in the past, but I recall that it caused some other issue (think it was other shared libraries were incompatible).
TIA!!

Static linking is still a viable option, since ncurses has few dependencies (libc, possibly gpm).  Doing that eliminates the stated problems with Fedora and OpenSUSE.
